# Redirect tee output to the variable instead of file

Tags: bash, curl, jq, tee

I'm trying to do the loop where output of each curl command which is returning json data is allocated to the variable/array. I'm using tee command to get my wanted value plus next token for next json piece of data. When I save data to file everything works fine but instead of saving data to file I would like to keep it in array/variable.

This works:

```
while  [[ "$next_token" != "null" ]]

do

curl -u "$user:$password" "https://mylink.dot" \
    | tee >(jq -r '.dataSummaries[] | .dataId' >> my_data_file.txt ) \
    >(jq -r '.nextToken'>next_token_file.txt) > /dev/null

next_token=$(cat next_token_file.txt)

done
```

I tried this:

```
while  [[ "$next_token" != "null" ]]

do
index=$((index+1))

curl -u "$user:$password" "https://mylink.dot" | tee >(jq -r '.dataSummaries[] | .dataId' | read my_array[index] ) >(jq -r '.nextToken'>next_token_file.txt) > /dev/null

next_token=$(cat next_token_file.txt)

done
```

When I use `|read var` my variable is empty.

How in this case can I store json data (and next token) in variable, not file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `jq` should read from the standard output of `tee`, then write to standard output. This entire pipeline is then put in another process substitution for `read` to read from.

```
read next_token <( curl -u "$user:$password" "https://mylink.dot" |
                     tee >(jq -r '.dataSummaries[] | .dataId' >> my_data_file.txt ) |
                     jq -r '.nextToken')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning to use this mechanism to get both values as variable.

```
read var1 var2 <<<$(curl -u "$user:$password" "https://mylink.dot" | tee >(jq -r '.dataSummaries[] | .dataId') >(jq -r '.nextToken') > /dev/null)
```